# Curly quotation marks become question marks in SQL when doing save() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

TLDR:
Using Hibernate, when trying to save any string with curly quotation marks in an Unicode SQL column, i.e. `‘ ’ “ ”` , it comes out as `? ? ? ?`. What may be the cause of it?

---

In order to debug this problem, I have enabled the following Hibernate properties:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

The target SQL column is of the datatype `nvarchar(max)` and uses `UNICODE` as character set and `SQL_Scandinavian_CP850_CI_AS` as collation.

Now, when persisting a string of pairs of curly and straight quotation marks, Hibernate logs this when `save()`:

```
DEBUG o.hibernate.SQL - insert into project.data (Content) values (?)    
TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [‘ ’ “ ” '' " "]
```

Although it says 'VARCHAR', I have tried to specify it as `nvarchar(max)` in the JPA entity class. Not sure though if the columnDefinition does anything here.

```
@Column(name = "Content", columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL")
private String content;
```

Despite all of this, here is the entry that got saved in the database: `[? ? ? ? '' " "]`. If you were now to update the entry directly in SQL with quotation marks, it would work as expected. Not sure what has happened between save() and SQL entry generation.

I am out of ideas to debug further. Any ideas?

Comment: This behaviour happens when UTF-8 characters are converted to ASCII. they just get replaced by ?. I don't know what database you are using (MsSql, mySql) and my java background is not good but google something like 'java hibernate utf8 characters' and you'll get enough hits an samples talking about this. I don't mark this question as a duplicate as I'm not sure which question it really is a duplicate of.

Comment: I am using MsSQL. I do have 'UNICODE' as character set and not 'cp850'. AFAIK, collation is different from character set and handles only the sorting and comparison part. Why would it interfere with the character encoding?

Comment: I wasn't talking about collation. If java communicates with the db using ascii (because config somewhere) the same character conversion could occur. If the hibernate connection has a character set option, then testing with utf-8 seems a valid try, as that seems to handle connection not collation.